# kill main thead from child thread python

Tags: python, windows

I want to kill the main process when the function check_Temp exits/raises an exception. I know this might not be the best way of doing this but I have to integrate a lot of code, and this is much easier. Also, I do want a hard shutdown so it doesn't matter if I get some errors after shutting the program.

I tried os.taskskill(), sys.exit(). os.exit() etc but the child process does not kill the main process.I don't mind if all the python processes get killed.
psutil download is firewalled by my company's helpful IT department, so I was wondering if someone has another solution.

```
import threading
import time
import os
from subprocess import call  
#import psutil

def check_Temp(temp, delay, run_event,pid):
    while run_event.is_set(): ##code for checking temperature will go here.
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "temp is %s \n"%temp
        temp=temp-1
        #print os.getpid()
        if temp<=38:
            raise Exception('LowTemp')
            #call('pkill python', shell=True)  
            os.popen('TASKKILL /PID '+str(pid)+' /F')
            #os.killall()
            #sys.exit() #want to exit main loop here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_event = threading.Event()
    run_event.set()
    temp =45
    d1=.1
    #print os.getpid()
    pid=os.getpid();
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = check_Temp, args = (temp,d1,run_event,pid))
    t1.start()
    print "Starting"

 ########## main code will go here, just have a simple counter here to test the functionality.

    x=25
    try:
        while 1:
            time.sleep(.1)
            x=x-1 
            print "x is %s \n"%x
            if x<0:
                print "x is %s"%x
                raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
            #exit()
    except Exception as e:
        print e     # the exception instance
        run_event.clear()
        t1.join()
        print "thread successfully closed"
```

Output is

```
Starting
temp is 45

x is 24

temp is 44

x is 23

temp is 43

x is 22

temp is 42

x is 21

temp is 41

x is 20

temp is 40

x is 19

temp is 39

x is 18

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\PythonSv\multithread6.py", line 14, in check_Temp
    raise Exception('LowTemp')
Exception: LowTemp

x is 17

x is 16

x is 15

x is 14

x is 13

x is 12

x is 11

x is 10

x is 9

x is 8

x is 7

x is 6

x is 5

x is 4

x is 3

x is 2

x is 1

x is 0

x is -1

x is -1
('spam', 'eggs')
thread successfully closed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use flags and callbacks not exceptions.

```
import threading
import time
import os
from subprocess import call

def check_Temp(temp, delay, run_event,pid, endit):
    while run_event.is_set():
        time.sleep(delay)
        ##code for checking temperature will go here.
        print "temp is %s \n"%temp
        temp=temp-1
        #print os.getpid()
        if temp<=38:
            print 'LowTemp %s!' % (temp, )
            endit()
            run_event.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_ok = True
    def Terminator():
        global run_ok
        print "Terminating"
        run_ok = False

    run_event = threading.Event()
    run_event.set()
    temp =45
    d1=.1
    #print os.getpid()
    pid=os.getpid();
    run_ok = True
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = check_Temp, args = (temp,d1,run_event,pid, Terminator))
    t1.start()
    print "Starting"

 ########## main code will go here, just have a simple counter here to test the functionality.

    x=25
    try:
        while run_ok:
            time.sleep(.1)
            x=x-1
            print "x is %s "%x
            if x<0:
                print "x is %s"%x
                raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
            #exit()
        t1.join()
        print 'Finished!'
```