# Python script is killed from within, but the process doesn't die

Tags: php, python, linux, exec

I'm trying to execute a python script using php with an exec command like this:

```
exec("python /address/to/script.py");
```

I don't need the script to run to completion, so after it does what I need, I call `sys.exit()` from within it. Execution is passed back to the php script, which is great, however the python process is still running. I can see it in my server's process list. Is there more that's required to fully kill it?

**Additional Info**

- The python script was written by a third party.
- I know very little about python, just enough to add the `sys.exit()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script could still be executing some cleanup code, or you could be calling `sys.exit()` from a child process which will essentially be calling `thread.exit()`, leaving the parent process running.

Check that the `sys.exit()` call is in the main part of the script and that no error handling is interfering with the `SystemExit` exception, or alternatively you could try `os._exit()`. Also ensure that an ampersand (`&`) is not present within the command passed to `exec()` as this will cause the script to run as a background process.

**Note** that `os._exit()` is not favourable since it doesn't do any cleanup, and essentially ends the process immediately.

**Edit** To end the script from within your `try` block you could do something like this:

```
try:
    # Existing Code
except SysExit:
    os._exit() # quit the process
except:
    # Existing error handling
```

Ideally the application logic should make use of message passing or something similar so that a child thread could notify the main thread that it should terminate.

Comment: No, & is not present. I need to execute it syncronously. Is there a way to determine within the script if I'm inside a child process? I know how to print output. Anyways, os._exit() sounds like it should be fine. As far as cleanup, do you just mean program specific stuff? The server state should be unaffected if I repeatedly killed the script forcefully every time, right?

Comment: There's some techniques for checking whether child processes are running [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442651/check-if-the-main-thread-is-still-alive-from-another-thread) that you could try. Cleanup would be program specific stuff, flushing buffers etc. although it shouldn't affect the server state. It's no different than killing the process via the `kill` command in the terminal.

Comment: Well I tried using `os._exit()` and it seems to trigger exception handling in their script. Still doesn't die, just outputs a message to the terminal. But I found `search_thread = Thread()` and `search_thread.start()` calls in the main file (the file I'm `sys.exit()`-ing from runs a search loop, so it's probably the child thread). Is there a simple way to send a notification to the parent and kill it there?

Comment: Ah, yup. The search loop is within a `try:` block. Is there a way to disable exception handling only for kill commands?

Comment: What to do is add another `except:` clause above all of the others to catch the `SystemExit` and then call `sys.exit()`. See my edit above.

Comment: If that doesn't work you'll need to use flags between the main process and threads. There's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064901/kill-main-thead-from-child-thread-python).

Comment: Got it. I had to use `os._exit()` in the exception handler instead of `sys.exit()` though. I think that's what you meant. Might wanna update the answer in case someone else stumbles here. Thanks brotha.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks will update it for future reference.